# Problem with outputlink on files

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 project using Mojarra, PrimeFaces and Tomcat 6.x.

I created some outputlink that point to files. These files are external of my WAR in a directory under Apache HTTPD's control.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{fileItem.linkTarget.sourceUrl}">#{fileItem.boname} (#{fileItem.linkTarget.mediaType})</h:outputLink>
```

The sourceUrl is value like `/dir/subDir/file.pdf`. When my sourceUrl doesn't contains space it's work. But when its contains space, they are are replace by `+`.
`/dir/subDir/big file.pdf` become `/dir/subDir/big+file.pdf`. When i replace the `+` with space in a normal webbrowser, it's work?

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

I get the same problem with graphicImage of mojarra and i solve by using Primefaces's graphicImage.

Answer (score 2):

In general I would not recommend to use blank spaces in urls.

If you have no influence on the file names in the url's you should url-encode these names as described here [URL-Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). The blank space has to be replaced by %20. Maybe there is a java class that does the encoding for you. I only know it from PHP, there you have a function like urlEncode().